Could not install packages due to an OS Error
I tried installing opal using the following cmd commands
pip install opal-client
pip install opal-server

but it shows this error
WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: 
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 
'C:\\Python312\\Scripts\\pygmentize.exe' -> 'C:\\Python312\\Scripts\\pygmentize.exe.deleteme'

I tried looking for solutions but there aren't much about Opal in the internet.

I looked for information on Opal and foundopal 0.23.0. But that shows the package as a single product. Is that what you are trying to install?

Doesn't look like an opal-specific problem to me. Make sure you're running the pip install commands in a cmd window invoked as Administrator (or more generally, a user with write permissions to C:\Python312\Scripts); if you want to do this as an unprivileged user, create a virtualenv under your home directory (C:\Users\Yourname) and do the installation there.

@OldBoy  They appear to be using this project, where OPAL stands for "Open Policy Administration Layer".  Although, Ithe opal tag applied to the question appears to be a 3rd project named opal, so it's really not 100% clear what they were intending to install.

@Ritam26  Could you clarify which project you are trying to use by including a link to it?  There are multiple projects named Opal, and the tag you added to your question appears to be intended for a C++ Open licensed Physics engine API.

@nigh_anxiety Hence my question.

@nigh_anxiety Yes, I am taking about Open Policy Administration Layer https://github.com/permitio/opal

@Ritam26  Could you update the original post to include that link, please?
Are you able to install other python packages without any issues?  Are you working in a virtualenv or are you trying to install it into your system packages directory?  This mostly looks like a permissions issue with not being able to access the location.  I just did a test install into a clean virtualenv and it worked fine.

just add --user to your command
